# Securing a client in IdentityServer4

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have the following scenario:

[image]

I am confused as to how to set up **API 2** in IdentityServer4, as it looks to me like it's both a `Client` (since it's consuming the resources provided by **API 1**) and an `ApiResource` (since I'm wanting to secure it so that only logged-in users can access it).

I have considered setting up **API 2** as a `Client` and securing it with cookie authentication. I think this is similar to what they do in the MvcClient in their [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess). However, I don't like it because all of the information about the user is stored server-side, so my JavaScript app has no way of knowing the user's name, email, etc.

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: does the call between api 1 and api 2 needs to have user data in it (claims etc.)?

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 Yes, it does.

Comment: So to make things clear - you need both API's secured by the same IDS, you need a user, who sends a requests to API 2 (and I guess other API's), but only requests coming to API 2, to be able to execute against API 1?

Comment: Correct. Basically, I want the user to be able to login to API 2 with their credentials, and then I want API 2 to send requests on behalf of that user to API 1.

Comment: But you don't want the user to be able to send straight calls to API 1

Comment: I suppose it would be fine if the user has the ability to send straight calls to API 1. My JavaScript app won't be configured to talk straight to API 1, but it's fine if the user has the *ability* to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172711/discussion-between-m3n7alsnak3-and-mshindal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to protect both of your API's with your Identity Server. Something like:

**API 1 Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) 
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => 
{ 
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000"; 
    options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Both; 
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; 
    options.ApiName = "api1"; 
});
```

Same thing for API 2, but the `options.ApiName` should be different. Then, your javascript client, when being constructed on the Identity Server side, should be allowed to access these 2 api's (allowed scopes):

```
new Client
    {
        ClientId = "your.js.client.id",

        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

        RedirectUris =           { "http://localhost:5003/callback.html" },
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/index.html" },
        AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:5003" },

        AllowedScopes =
        {
            "api2",
            "api1"
        }
    }
```

This code was from the [official documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html).

And then in API 2, when you want to call API 1's controller, you need something like:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost/api1/test");
```

Where you get the `access_token`:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> ControllerMethodInApi2()
{
    var accessToken = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"); 

    return View();
}
```

This should work for you.